# Set-Cookie header missing from ajax response in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, ajax, django, cordova, cookies

My phonegap app communicates with django, so I use the method described in the following article to capture and send csrftoken:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/

This has been working till iOS 10.3. 
In iOS 10.3, the ajax call gets all response headers except Set-Cookie.
I tried adding xhrFields: {withCredentials: true} and crossDomain: true but it makes no difference.

Here is the request to get the csrftoken:

```
 $.ajax({beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.withCredentials = true;},
    type: "GET",
    url: 'url', // the django view has @ensure_csrf_cookie set     
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      // returns null in iOS 10.3
      document.cookie = xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"); 
    },
});
```

The same code works fine in iOS 10.2 and we can save the csrftoken from "Set-Cookie" header for later use.
iOS 10.3 somehow prevents this "Set-Cookie" response header from appearing in the xhr object, thus we cannot get the csrftoken from server and any subsequent POST action will be forbidden.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior, I got the same issue. Couldn't find any official Apple doc about the change. There is a Cordova plugin that make cookies work in iOS and Android that could help you there. (I haven't tried it yet)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the behavior.  I think the root problem might not be cookie itself, but that the Set-Cookie header sent from server is somehow missing from the http response object.  Calling xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() will return all expected headers except Set-cookie which should contain the csrftoken we need. iOS 10.3 may no longer allow Set-Cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to work around the problem by using a third party Cordova plugin, thanks to Selim Arsever's suggestion.

Steps:

Ask django to generate a csrftoken and send the data to my app via JsonResponse;

Use cookieMaster's setCookieValue to set the csrftoken to the domain cookie.

The csrftoken can then be retrieved to send to django in subsequent POST calls.

Comment: Guys, would be so kind a provide the link to that cordova plugin? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I used the following plugin: https://github.com/kristianhristov/cordova-cookie-master